# Using HLM - using intercept to predict slope

Tags: modeling, linear, multilevel-analysis

A common question I get from other faculty members is when they are conducting a longitudinal analysis, i.e., pre-test and post-test, they wonder if where the participants' score at pre-test, i.e., initial level, is associated with their score at post-test, i.e., ending level. in other words, where the participants ended up is largely due to where they started. As an example, I am conducting a study on mindfulness training where we measure their mindfulness ability before and after the training. Although we found a positive effect from pre-test to post-test, observers were curious if those who already had high mindfulness abilities at pre-test would have high mindfulness abilities at post-test. Therefore the training would not change their mindfulness levels that much because the participants already had high mindfulness abilities when they entered the treatment. 
to answer this question, I thought about using correlations between the pre-test and post-test scores. the higher the score on the pre-test, the higher the score on the post-test. and there is a moderate correlation value. no surprise there. 
I guess my question though was more about (a) if you had a high pre-test score, is your growth in mindfulness from pre-test to post-test flat, i.e., not much change because of a ceiling effect, or (b) if you had a low pre-test score, is your growth in mindfulness from pre-test to post-test a linear progression because when you start low, there is no where to go but up.
I thought about using HLM to answer this question. I will first state that you could probably tell I am a novice HLM user.
 Could I use variance in intercepts, e.g., at pre-test, and use the intercepts to predict mindfulness slope? If so, how would I set up the Level 1 and level 2 models for a growth curve?
I tried setting up this model (four waves (pre, post, follow-up 1, follow-up 2). I added a quadratic effect):

Level-1 Model

```
MINDFULN = P0 + P1*(WAVE) + P2*(WAVESQ) + e
```

Level-2 Model

```
P0 = B00 + r0
P1 = B10 + r1
P2 = B20 + r2
```

Mixed Model

```
MINDFULN = B00
  + B10*WAVE
  + B20*WAVESQ  + r0 + r1*WAVE  + r2*WAVESQ + e
```

I got the tau as correlation matrix:
tau (as correlations)

```
INTRCPT1,P0  1.000 -0.707  0.680
    WAVE,P1 -0.707  1.000 -0.997
  WAVESQ,P2  0.680 -0.997  1.000
```

I am getting the impression that my model will not allow me to examine this hypothesis. Is there a way I could set up the model to test the hypothesis that those participants with an already high mindfulness ability at pre-test will likely not experience much increase in their mindfulness ability over time, but those participants with a low mindfulness ability at pre-test will likely experience more increases in their mindfulness ability over time?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of problems associated with regression toward the mean. Someone  initially high in mindfulness won't be expected to increase as much as someone low in mindfulness even if the true effect of the training is the same for all levels of mindfulness.